# How can I properly use sed to remove text outside "" characters?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have text `aaaaaa"bbbbb"aaaa` I only want to output `bbbbb`

I have tried `sed -e 's/"\(.*\)"/\1/'` but it just cuts only the `"` characters. How do I filter this properly

Comment: Should we assume that this text is in a file? Or is it part of an command's output, or is it in a variable?

Comment: 1. Will there be just one substring enclosed in double-quotes? Or can there be more than one? 2. This seems like a job for `grep` - why `sed`?

Comment: @mathguy how would I do it with grep

Comment: I already showed how in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` does not just output whatever is in the "right-side" of the `s` command. It replaces the left-side match with the right-side and outputs the resulting line (or, more technically, the pattern space).

```
echo 'aa"bb"aa'|sed 's/"\(.*\)"/\1/'
```

That left-side regex matches `"bb"`. It is substituted by what the capture group captured: `bb`. Then, the output is `aabbaa`.

Note how different the above is from

```
echo 'aa"bb"aa'|sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/'
```

That regex matches the whole line, so that `aa"bb"aa` is substituted by `bb`, which is the output.

Another possible tool is `awk`:

```
echo 'aa"bb"aa'|awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
```

Here the `"` was used as delimiter and the second field is printed.

Answer (score 4):

Easy work with `cut`.

If the text is coming from stdin:

```
echo 'aaaaaa"bbbbb"aaaa' | cut -d\" -f2
```

If the text is in a file called `filename`:

```
cut -d\" -f2 filename
```

Explanation of the `cut` command:

- `-d\"` tells `cut` the delimiter is `"` (the `\` is for escaping, otherwise the shell will complain about unclosed quote)
- `-f2` tells `cut` to grab the second field (delimited by `"` above)

Answer (score 1):

As you want a `sed` solution, here is one in combination with `tr`:

```
echo 'aaaaaa"bbbbb"aaaa' | tr '"' '\n' | sed -n 2p
```

or use `awk`:

```
echo 'aaaaaa"bbbbb"aaaa' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
```

(I would still prefer `cut`, see [@GMaster's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584399/236063)).

Answer (score 1):

`grep` solution (using lookahead, and therefore PCRE option):

```
grep -oP '(?<=")[^"]*(?=")'
```